# Redirect back to page tab after user authenticates?

Tags: facebook, authentication, iframe, redirect

How should I go about redirecting the user back to my page's tab after they authenticate my app? I cannot put one specific url in for the redirect since my app will live on multiple pages. So somehow I need to grab the page's id and put it into the url. I've tried to use session variables but it doesn't seem to be working for me. :( Here's a portion of my code...

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$_SESSION['TrueID'] = $signed_request['page']['id']; 

$fbconfig['appBaseUrl'] = "http://www.facebook.com/pages/".$_SESSION['TrueID']."/".$_SESSION['TrueID']."?sk=app_241321439259320";

/* 
 * If user first time authenticated the application facebook
 * redirects user to baseUrl, so I checked if any code passed
 * then redirect him to the application url 
 * -mahmud
 */
if (isset($_GET['code'])){
    header("Location: " . $fbconfig['appBaseUrl']);
    exit;
}
//~~

//
if (isset($_GET['request_ids'])){
    //user comes from invitation
    //track them if you need
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to set a session variable to grab the page's id.. but that's not working for me :(  The variable echo's out just fine when I visit my page.. but I'm guessing its getting lost somewhere during the authentication.

Comment: Alright.. this might be totally ridiculous but I got it to work by inserting this javascript that will send the browser back 2 pages instead of redirecting to another page.. 

<script>history.go(-2)</script>

It works.. but should I be doing it this way?

Answer (score 3):

So when a Page add/install your app, you should store the page's `link` along with the page's `id`.

Now when your page tab is loaded, Facebook will send the `page` parameter which will contain the page `id` (along with other info, refer to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs)). You retrieve that id, get the page's link from your db and construct your page tab link, which would be something like (where `$page` is the page's db record):

```
$redirect_uri = $page['page_link'] . '?sk=app_' . $APP_ID
```

Since you are using the PHP-SDK, this is how you construct your login:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if(!$user) {
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri, 'scope' => 'read_stream'));
    echo "<script>top.location.href = '$url';</script>";
    exit;
}
```

Of course you may not want to redirect to the login directly but instead have a call to action link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url;?>" target="_top">Connect</a>
```

Comment: How are you getting `$page['page_link']`?

Comment: If you are installing the app through the graph api ([reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs)) then you already know the `page_id` you just query that id through the graph an get the data. Otherwise, if you came across a new page (captured by the `signed_request`) just retrieve its info & add it to your DB...etc

Answer (score 2):

Best way I found is to set the Site URL in the app settings to http://www.facebook.com/pages/

Then do something like this(tested):

```
$uid = '';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  =>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'secret' =>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'cookie' => true,
    'oauth'  => true,
        ));

$uid = $facebook->getUser();

$signedrequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$page_id = $signedrequest["page"]["id"]; 

$fb_access_token = $signedrequest["oauth_token"];

if($uid==''){
echo '<div id="authenticate"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=APP_CLIENT_ID_HERE&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/pages/'. $page_id .'/'.$page_id.'%3Fsk%3Dapp_APP_CLIENT_ID_HERE&response_type=token" target="_top">Authorize App</a></div>';
```

This might be a little bit of a hack, but it works well for my situation:) Hope it helps someone!